# Using the python installation bundled inside a 3rd party app

Tags: python

[QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) for Windows contains a python installation which I would like to use without firing up QGIS.

I can find the executable

```
c:\program files\qgis pisa\bin\python.exe
```

But if I try running that, Python says

```
ImportError:  No module named site
```

presumably because it can't find its standard library.  Firing up QGIS and checking `sys.path` from within, I see this

```
C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools
```

Which suggests to me that the standard library is in

```
c:\program files\qgis pisa\apps\python27
```

So I try

```
set PYTHONHOME=c:\program files\qgis pisa\apps\python27
c:\program files\qgis pisa\bin\python.exe
```

But still,

```
ImportError:  No module named site
```

What is the correct way to run python from the location it's installed in here?

Comment: Are you sure there is a module named site in there? is the module installed?

Comment: If I set PYTHONPATH to the entire python path listed from *within* QGIS, it works, so `site` must be in there.  But I suspect this isn't the *correct* approach.

Comment: site.py appears in both `C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\Lib` and `C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages`

Comment: So where is site in relation to your file?

Comment: Relative to `python.exe`, it's `..\apps\python27\lib\site.py` or `..\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\site.py`(these are different files by the way, so I'm not sure which is the "right" one)

Comment: You should have the correct folders (lib and site-packages) in some sort of path variable so that they would work. unless it's an internal module.

Comment: Just putting those two folders on PYTHONPATH doesn't work, but copying the entire path above does.  Maybe the correct way is to copy the entire path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105160/discussion-between-glados-and-sideshow-bob).